# catch notifications OneSignal react-native

Tags: react-native, push-notification, notifications, push

there is an application written in react-native, OneSignal is used as push notifications, my task is to catch pushes and save them to local storage when the application is closed, at the moment I can only catch when the application is either open or running in the background tell me is it possible to do it? I did not find anything suitable in the OneSignal documentation, thanks.

Comment: You can use `notifee` library to work with OneSignal notifications: https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/integrations/onesignal. and listen to the background events: https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/events#background-events. If this works with tell me to write as an answer

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and post the results

Comment: I couldn’t integrate, for some reason they work for me separately, I didn’t catch a single push at all

Comment: Hi, it didn’t work for me, I got the solution from technical support, thanks https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/create-an-activity-feed

Comment: Hi Андрей Кожин! If you found the solution to your answer, please write it as an answer so other people having the same issue can find it easily.

Comment: Hi, there is no answer, I found out that it is necessary to make the application wake up every time a notification arrives, but react native cannot do this (